# How can you remove outline around matInput tag when you set input type=number using tailwindcss

Tags: angular-material, tailwind-css

I use Angular material and tailwindcss together. When I apply matInput when using the input element, there is no problem, but when I set the input type as a number, when I focus on the input component, an outline is created around the component. As seen in the picture below.

[image: input outline]

Answer (score 3):

This works for other types of input so it may work for this one as well.
I used Tailwind CSS's class "`outline-none`"

Answer (score 2):

Thank God I finally figured it out. I've been dealing with this for three days. None of the suggestions [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1231) have worked for me. I use angular material and talwincss together. When I make the input type number in the MatInput component, when I click on the component, an outline appears around the input part. Finally, in the **tailwind.config.js** file, I deleted the **[require ('@ tailwindcss / forms')]** part in the plugin array and it was fixed. Thank goodness I found it. :)

```
module.exports = {
prefix: '',
purge: {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{html,ts}',
  ]
},
darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
theme: {
  extend: {},
},
variants: {
  extend: {},
},
plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'),require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
```

};

[image: input otuline tailwindcss]
[image: removed outline]

Comment: I've been dealing with this problem for many days, and this is exactly what i've been looking for. Thank you so much!